# Limit upload speed on c#

Tags: c#, limit, bandwidth, minio

Im building an app to upload clips auto to a Minio S3 server.
When im playing and save a clip, the app uses 100% of bandwidth and this is so annoying.
I need to limit the upload speed to complete this, Thanks!

My upload string:

```
await s3.PutObjectAsync(bucketName, objectName, filePath, contentType);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that with any built in functions, but one thing you could try is handling the transfer yourself at your own rate by writing a custom `ThrottledStream`.

That exercise will teach you how difficult what you want is to get right (for example, you can't just send X amount of data every second), so that's also a plus!

Comment: I tried this but dosent work with s3, i dont know how stream the s3.putObject function.
Im very new on c# and dosent have so much idea how to solve it

Comment: It doesn't work or you don't know how to stream? Which is it?