# Limit upload speed on C# with AWS S3 SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, bandwidth

I am developing an application that has to upload files from 500mb to 1GB, but I need to limit the speed of uploading the files, because if I do not do it, the application consumes 100% bandwidth and does not allow other programs to use the connection correctly.
I'm using the AWS SDK for S3 in C# and couldn't find a way to limit it. Check and in other languages ​​like Python if it has a function to limit the bandwidth but in C# I didn't find anything like it

I would like to know if this can be done in C# to be able to complete my application, thank you very much

```
  public async Task UploadDataFileAsync(string data, string storageKeyId, string storageSecret, string region)
        {
            var regionIdentifier = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region);
            using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(storageKeyId, storageSecret, regionIdentifier))
            {
                try
                {
                    var putRequest1 = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = AwsBucketName,
                        Key = AwsBucketFileName,
                        ContentBody = data,
                        ContentType = "application/json"
                    };

                    await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest1);
                }
                catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
                {
                    if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                        (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") || amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
                    {
                        throw new SecurityException("Invalid Amazon S3 credentials - data was not uploaded.", amazonS3Exception);
                    }

                    throw new HttpRequestException("Unspecified error attempting to upload data: " + amazonS3Exception.Message, amazonS3Exception);
                }

                var response = await client.GetObjectAsync(AwsBucketName, AwsBucketFileName);
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How does this differ from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73000864/limit-upload-speed-on-c-sharp)

Comment: Previously I was using the MiniO client to connect to the S3 server, but I didn't find any documentation on how to limit it. In the AWS SDK there are functions to limit the upload speed, but I can't find the corresponding one in C#

Comment: Can you point us to some of these "functions to limit the upload speed"?